# How to pass some data to last gin handler

Tags: go

I am running a gin router and defined a API like this

```
versionOneApis.GET(/details, myfunc1("my data") , myfunc2)
```

My myfunc2 has the following signature

```
func myfunc2 (c *gin.Context) {

    c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "my details")
}
```

I want to pass some  data into myfunc2. I am able to pass data into myfunc1 whose signature is

```
func myfunc1 (somedata string) {
   fmt.Println(somedata)       
}
```

But I am not able to pass data into myfunc2 as I cannot pass a *gin.Context and my data together and if I dont pass 2 values then I get an error saying that 2 inputs are required for myfunc2.

How can I pass data to myfunc2 which already has a *gin.Context input paramter?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot pass such a handler like `myfunc1("my data")` to the `GET` method.

I guess you might need something like this:

```golang
func myfunc1(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Set("key1", "value1")
}

func myfunc2(c *gin.Context) {
    value, exists := c.Get("key1")
    fmt.Printf("value: %s, exists: %t\n", value, exists)
}

versionOneApis.GET("/details", myfunc1 , myfunc2)
```

if you want to get a parameter from query string, you can do it through `c.Query("param_name")`